# Batch resize in photoshop to specific size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm running a CS5 photoshop droplet to try and resize images dropped in to resize to the following:

```
300px wide @ 72dpi. The height can be arbitrary depending on image dimensions.
```

The images I'm inputting could be various sizes/DPI and so not everything is equal.

The problem I'm having is that the due to the size being in relation to DPI I can't change DPI and Width at the same time. The batch I used basically made them at 300px wide but spat it out at 300DPI (I fed in a 300DPI picture).

I tried running two sets of resize actions but that didn't work and neither did the save for web option (i resized to 300px and hoped for an outputted file would default to 72DPI but it didn't.

Any ideas?
Cheers, 
C

Comment: As long as you set resolution before width and height, you should be good.

Comment: @Joonas That got it! Cheers, it was just a simple issue of the ordering. Thanks very much!